# $injector:modulerr error in angularjs (angular-ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load a template with ui-router in angular js. These are my html and js files.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>     
        <title>AngularJS UI Routing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <a href='#/first-msg'>link</a>
        <div ui-view></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <script src="application.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

application.js

```
   var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: '/first-msg',
        template: '<strong>hi this is 1st message</strong>'
    });
}])
```

Comment: And so what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject ui.router to the module,

```
   var app = angular.module('app', [ui.router]);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: '/first-msg',
        template: '<strong>hi this is 1st message</strong>'
    });
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>     
        <title>AngularJS UI Routing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
</head>
 <body ng-app="app">
<a href='#/first-msg'>link</a>
<div ui-view></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell me about this error. html is same and home.html contains <strong>{{message}}</strong>


var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('firstMessage', {
        url: '/first-msg',
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller("homeCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "This is home";
}]);